# OAuth Authentication & Azure

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, office-365, azure, oauth

I'm new to SharePoint development and using Office 365 SharePoint 2013.

We need to replace our AD cloud based authentication servers with OAuth authentication.

Am I correct in thinking that our SP users would still be managed in Azure AD and synchronised to SP?